# Emulator Not Displaying Specified Font

Tags: c#, xaml, visual-studio-2013, windows-phone-8.1

I have my XAML codes wired to the C# codes (for events handling and stuffs) just that when the emulator launches, it picks up the default fonts for the textblocks. I have custom fonts set. For example:

```
    <TextBlock x:Name="welcomeTextblock" 
               TextWrapping="Wrap" 
               FontSize="40"
               Foreground="Purple"
               Margin="21,117,21,475" 
               FontFamily="Arial">
        HI!
    </TextBlock>
```

For some reason, when I deploy it, it takes the custom font (Segoe UI, I believe). I have closed VS and reopened and also rebooted my computer. I am still getting the same issue!

It is the same scenario with

```
Text="Hi"
```

, inside the block.
I have changed the background colour setting of the XAML pages also (to isolate the issue), and they take affect just fine. I am having trouble with only the fonts!

Have you seen anything like this before? I am sure there's a way.

Comment: Why do you have a margin set to such numbers? Is that causing the text to not be shown? Can you provide screenshots of the problem?

Comment: Hi @OmegaMan: I am sorry I cannot give you the screenshot. It is a private project, and I wish not to disclose it. i dont suppose margins is causing the issue. My problem is with the font, not with the text itself. when the page loads, i can input the text (init he textbox) just fine. But the font for the TEXTBLOCK is what is causing the issue here. It only is rendering the default font, and not the one I am putting in, in this case, Ariel.

Comment: Can you create a test side project which demonstrates the issue? I wonder if it is an environmental issue with your current project where a new project would not have it.

Answer (score 0):

Your textblock may be in a container which is overriding its font. I recommend that you create a test project which tries to recreate the issue. If the issue is not re-createable, then the issue will be found within the environment of the xaml of the main project. If it is found, by providing the example project's xaml here on SO we will be able to determine the issue.

Comment: So I tried to recreate the issue, but it apparently works fine, except that the non MS default fonts do not load (i have no idea what is going on). In my original project though, I have tried Century Gothic (MS default) and comic sans (default again). Apparently, century gothic doesn't want to load on the emulator, but comic sans deos. any idea what is the issue here? In my test project though, MS default fonts loaded, and not the other ones

Comment: i've also changed the font at the page level, but the issue persists,and that too only with century gothic. The emulator loads fine with comic sans, or any other fonts

Comment: Updated to VS2013 Update4, still the same bloody issue. I think, for certain, VS emulators don't load Century Gothic font, unless I am missing something.

Comment: Something new: the fonts in the test project display fine on the Store emulator. Same with my project. The Store emulator accepts the font "Century Gothic" just fine.. It's just with the Phone emulator. And i'd hate to uninstall/re-install, as I've updated the application already! Thanks!

Comment: I managed to fix this issue by recreating the project from the scratch.. And a little bit of copying-pasting the code also.. Thanks to those who tried to help :)

Comment: @AnonymousPerson since the advice I gave was to create a test project, is there a reason you have not marked this as the answer? Thanks.

Comment: @AnonymousPerson I wasn't trying to be rude. If there is an answer, feel free to answer it yourself (it is allowed on Stack Overflow). Otherwise it is appears that this question is still open; hence why I asked why you haven't marked an answer. You said yourself that the answered was found due to creating a test project. Which was my advice as provided...hence my confusion on not marking the answer. Nothing more nothing less.

Comment: I am sorry about my misconduct. I took it the wrong way.. Regardless, have a nice day! And thanks again..